# Using automator and AppleScript to move a file to a different folder and subfolder based on name and content of a file

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, pdf

I'm a total newbie on Automator and Scripting... I have read a lot of answers to problems a bit similar to mine, but I don't succeed to adapt with Automator + AppleScript.

Here is what I want to do:

When I download a file to a directory `/Volumes/Macboot /Downloads`, (yes there is a space in the HDD's name), e.g. `statement_EUR_2020-05-01_2020-05-31.pdf`.

I verify if the file is with extension pdf + it contains an IBAN + the name contains "statement".
[image: filter for the document]

If the file corresponds, I want to verify the year and month in the name and move it accordingly to the good Google Drive folder:

> /Volumes/Macboot /Travail en cours/Google
>   Drive/Company/Comptabilité/**2020**/**05**/Compte Transferwise 1/

With help from @Solar Mike, here is what I'm attempting:
What I am doing without success right now:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        set theFile to input as text
        set copyFile to input as alias
        set yearName to ((characters 34 thru -1 of theFile) as string) --trim first 35
        set yearName to ((characters 1 thru -22 of yearName) as string) --trim last 23
        set monthName to ((characters 39 thru -1 of theFile) as string)
        set monthName to ((characters 1 thru -19 of monthName) as string)
        set destinationFolder to ("Macboot :Travail en cours:Google Drive:Company:Comptabilité:" & yearName & ":" & monthName & ":Compte Transferwise 1:Relevé PDF + fichier CSV:" as alias)
        copy copyFile to (destinationFolder) 
    end tell
end run
```

No error... but no copied file. 
yearName is good, as is monthName and destinationFolder, but perhaps I don't use the good method to copy?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used this:

```
tell application "Finder"
activate
        set source_folder to choose folder with prompt "Please choose the Source-Folder:" default location ((path to home folder) as alias)
        set source_files to every file in source_folder
        set target_folder to choose folder with prompt "Please choose the Taget-Folder:" default location (":Applications:" as alias)
        repeat with i from 1 to number of items in source_files
                set source_file to (item i of source_files)
                copy source_file to (target_folder) -- use "copy source_file to folder (target_folder as alias)" to copy the files
        end repeat
        set question to display dialog "  Files have  been moved.
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Solar Mike, I've tried line by line and found how to do it.
My code :

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set theFile to input as text
    set yearName to ((characters 34 thru -1 of theFile) as string) --trim first 35
    set yearName to ((characters 1 thru -22 of yearName) as string) --trim last 23
    set monthName to ((characters 39 thru -1 of theFile) as string)
    set monthName to ((characters 1 thru -19 of monthName) as string)
    set destinationFolder to ("Macboot :Travail en cours:Google Drive:Company:Comptabilité:" & yearName & ":" & monthName & ":Compte Transferwise 1:Relevé PDF + fichier CSV:" as text)
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        move theFile to destinationFolder -- use "copy source_file to folder (target_folder as alias)" to copy the files
    end tell
    set result to {yearName, monthName, theFile, destinationFolder}
    return result
end run
```

The problem from my early attempt was just with "copy" copying the name, not the file. But as I need it to be moved, now it's good.

Comment: Well done, good for you.